# Динамическое изменение полей счетчика

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть счетчик, подсчитывающий количество и сумму конкретной продукции. В `span` с классом `quantity` хранится количество и сумма в виде "13 x 70 руб." `input` c `type="number"` должен получать значение `quantity`, т.е. число 13.
`input` c `type="button"` увеличивают/уменьшают значение переменной `input` c `type="number"`, что должно также отражаться в `quantity`, а сумма - перезаписываться в `amount в полном виде, т.е. в виде "13*70 = 910 руб".

Сложность возникает в преобразовании строк в значения и в автоматическом отслеживании изменений с обменом информации между селекторами. В коде написал смысл того, что хочу получить.

```js
var quantity = $(".quantity").text();
$(".input-text.qty.text").val(quantity);
var amount = $(".amount").text();
var total = amount * quantity;
$(".quantity").text() = $(".input-text.qty.text").val(quantity);
$(".amount").text() = total;
```

```html
<span class="quantity">13 × <span class="amount">70&nbsp;руб.</span></span>
<div class="quantity buttons_added">
    <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="27" id="num_count" name="quantity" value="1" title="Кол." class="input-text qty text" size="4">
    <input type="button" value="+1" id="button_plus" class="plus">
    <input type="button" value="-1" id="button_minus" class="minus">
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идея в том, что повесить обработчик события `change` на элемент `#num_count` (который и `.input-text.qty.text`) и обработчики события `click` на элементы `#button_plus` и `#button_minus`. В этих обработчиках вызывается функция `changeCountValue`, которая меняет значения во всех нужных полях. Заодно добавлены проверки на валидность (не меньше минимума и не больше максимума) значения.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $count = $('#num_count');
    var $quantity = $(".quantity");
    var amount = parseInt($('.amount').text());
    var $sum = $('.sum');
    var minCount = parseInt($count.attr('min'));
    var maxCount = parseInt($count.attr('max'));
    
    $count.val($quantity.text());
    
    $count.on('change', function() {
        changeCountValue(0);
    });
    
    $('#button_plus').on('click', function() {
        changeCountValue(1);
    });
    
    $('#button_minus').on('click', function() {
        changeCountValue(-1);
    });
    
    function changeCountValue(change)
    {
        var newCount = parseInt($count.val()) + change;
        if (newCount < minCount) {
            newCount = minCount;        
        }
        else if (newCount > maxCount) {
            newCount = maxCount;
        }
        $count.val(newCount);
        $quantity.text(newCount);
        $sum.text(newCount * amount);
    }
});
```

```html
<span class="quantity">13</span> × <span class="amount">70</span> = <span class="sum">910</span> руб.
<div class="buttons_added">
    <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="27" id="num_count" name="quantity" value="1" title="Кол." class="input-text qty text" size="4" />
    <input type="button" value="+1" id="button_plus" class="plus" />
    <input type="button" value="-1" id="button_minus" class="minus" />
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: супер! а что делать, если сумма измеряется в тысячах и миллионах? parseInt ведь тогда не подойдет?

Comment: @Вася нет, `Number` и `parseInt()` в JS не имеют ограничения в тысячу, миллион или миллиард: [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/y7u6wjna/).

Comment: а запятые между тысячами они хорошо воспринимают? потому что, когда я переношу в свой код, то у меня обрезает сумму после запятой. и опять же после выполнения сложения/уменьшения $count.on('change', function() {
        changeCountValue(0);
    }); у меня с блока удаляется и остается только результат выполнения

Comment: @Вася если у вас неожиданно (потому что в вопросе ни слова про это нет) числа не целые, то вместо `parseInt()` нужно использовать `parseFloat()`. Для ограничения количества цифр после запятой при выводе можно использовать `.toFixed()`.

Comment: числа то целые, но они превосходят которые я указал здесь (для упрощения) и они у меня записаны в таком виде "360,000&nbsp;руб." - и почему-то из него parseFloat() вытаскивает только 360..

Comment: @Вася да, это нормально. Либо используйте какой-нибудь плагин для этого, либо что-нибудь вроде [этого кода](http://jsfiddle.net/y7u6wjna/1/).

Comment: ну проста какая-то загадка! просто перенес в код, который вы мне дали и в результате в логах показывает все равно 361.. на на это var amount = parseNumber($('.li .amount').text());
 console.log(amount);
здесь пишет NaN

Comment: нет, с ваши куском все в порядке - я просто в настройках заменил запятую на точку и в коде не поменял, но для моего участка по-прежнему пишет NaN

Comment: @Вася лучше задать новый вопрос, описав эту проблему и добавив в вопрос текущий код и пример, на котором работает неправильно. В комментариях весьма трудно в этом разобраться.

Comment: ок, как только разберусь что и где у меня не получается - так и сделаю

Comment: описал новую проблему в другом месте - [месте] (http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431541/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5)