# Получение числового значения из текста элемента

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужно получить значение `$('.li .amount').text()` в виде числа в переменную `amount` (`var amount = parseNumber($('.li .amount').text())`). Однако функция возвращает `NaN`.

```js
function parseNumber(n) {
    var parts = n.split('.');
    var result = 0;
    var multiplier = 1;
    for (var i = parts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        result += parseInt(parts[i]) * multiplier;
        multiplier *= 1000;
    }
    return result;
}
var amount = parseNumber($('.amount').text());
console.log(amount);
```

```html
<span class="amount">360.000&nbsp;руб.</span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Regent ну вот - постарался максимально уменьшить, чтобы можно было понять о чем суть

Comment: @Regent боюсь, что это невозможно или близко к невозможному, во всяком случае для меня, т.к. мне не понятно как отобразить в fiddle, функцию формирования элемента извне, на которой будет стоять обработчик с триггером и который будет добавлять в динамическую структуру класс с которым будет взаимодействовать класс .amount

Comment: Проведу аналогию: ваш шкаф не входит в мой грузовик. Вы говорите: "мой шкаф не входит в ваш грузовик. Что делать?". Я говорю: "предоставьте пример шкафа, чтобы я мог подобрать нужный грузовик". Вы говорите: "к сожалению, у меня не получается собрать шкаф перед вами и описать вам весь процесс его сборки". Я говорю: "процесс сборки не важен, равно как и где вы его собираете. Просто предоставьте готовый шкаф". И важный момент: нужен только шкаф, а не вся ваша мебельная фабрика, потому что искать в ней нужный шкаф - дело слишком долгое и неблагодарное.

Comment: @Regent так, я нарисовал шкаф в фидле и кажется понял - у меня строка на выходе <span class="amount">360.000&nbsp;руб.</span> возможно в результат  parseNumber попадает  "&nbsp;руб."

Comment: Правильно заданный вопрос - половина ответа :) Вопрос отредактирую, пару вариантов решения проблемы опишу в ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - вынести `&nbsp;руб.` за `<span>`. Это, во-первых, позволит не менять JS-код, во-вторых, при установке нового значения в `.amount` не придётся каждый раз дописывать `+ "&nbsp;руб."`.

Другой вариант, сохраняющий HTML-код - это использование регулярное выражение для выделения групп цифр из строки:

```js
function parseNumber(str) {
    var regExp = /\d+/g;
    var part;
    var result = 0;
    while (part = regExp.exec(str)) {
        result = result * Math.pow(10, part[0].length) + parseInt(part[0]);
    }
    return result;
}

var amount = parseNumber($('.amount').text());
console.log(amount);
```

```html
<span class="amount">360.000&nbsp;руб.</span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Минус этого подхода - строка `360 % 00 &nbsp;руб. 0` тоже будет преобразована к числу `360000` (реалистичность такого примера оставил вне рассмотрения).

Ещё один вариант: сначала выдернуть все цифры плюс точки из начала строки, опять-таки с помощью регулярного выражения, а затем воспользоваться исходным кодом:

```js
function parseNumber(str) {
    var regExp = /^[0-9\.]+/;
    var result = 0;
    var match = regExp.exec(str);
    var parts = match[0].split('.');
    var result = 0;
    var multiplier = 1;
    for (var i = parts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        result += parseInt(parts[i]) * multiplier;
        multiplier *= Math.pow(10, parts[i].length);
    }
    return result;
}

var amount = parseNumber($('.amount').text());
console.log(amount);
```

```html
<span class="amount">360.000&nbsp;руб.</span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: отлично! единственный момент, что у тебя получается значение без точки, а мне она нужна. В связи с чем возник производный вопрос, который описал здесь - [http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431638/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82]